# Adding a secondary Azure hosted ADFS 3 server to an on-premise ADFS 2 farm

Tags: azure, adfs

We currently have an on-premise ADFS 2 farm that's working with Office 365 and we're going to be moving offices shortly. We're thinking about adding a secondary ADFS 3 server in Azure and then make it primary prior to moving our office.

Here are some of the steps I'm considering:

- Setup a vpn tunnel between Azure and our on-premise network
- Join the new ADFS server on Azure to the domain
- Install the certificates on the new ADFS server
- Add the ADFS 3 role and join the ADFS farm
- Add an ADFS Proxy server in Azure in a DMZ network
- Make the Azure ADFS server primary
- Change DNS settings to point to the new Azure IP (internal and external)
- Disconnect and move ADFS 2 servers

Are there any other steps or gotchas that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete this migration successfully. Here are my observations in case someone else can use it in the future.

- It is not possible to join an ADFS 3 server to an existing ADFS 2 farm. However, it is possible to install and configure a new ADFS 3 farm while still using the ADFS 2 farm
- It is best to use the same service account UPN and certificate in order to minimize any discrepancies
- I found this article very helpful during this process: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2014/03/31/how-to-build-your-adfs-lab-part4-upgrading-to-server-2012-r2.aspx

In a nutshell here's what I did:

1. Create 2 ADFS servers and 2 ADFS proxy servers on Azure
2. Setup Azure tunnel with on-premise network
3. Join the 2 ADFS servers to domain
4. Import ADFS certificates
5. Add ADFS role and setup ADFS 3 farm
6. Test ADFS functionality by changing the hosts file and point the ADFS domain locally on both ADFS servers
7. Export ADFS settings from old servers and import into new servers
8. Test Office 365 federation using modified hosts file on test workstation
9. Change public DNS records to point to new ADFS 3 farm
10. Decommission the ADFS 2 farm